# select2: custom matcher - search through data array

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I'm struggling with **select2**.

Given this example json data:

```
{"id":1,"text":"search term category","data":[{"Key":"catalog","Value":"search term catalog"},{"Key":"make","Value":"search term make"},{"Key":"model","Value":"search term model"}]}
```

How can I search through not only the  **"text"** field but  all **"value"** fields in the **data array**?

I read about **custom matcher** but could not get it to work nor could I find an example I could work with.

Hope you can help me or provide me with a sample.

Thank you.

EDIT: Fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b85swr3b/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom matcher, examples are provided in the select2 [docs](https://select2.org/searching). I've modified their provided example to make it something that might work for you.

```
function matchCustom(params, data) {
    // If there are no search terms, return all of the data
    if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
      return data;
    }

    // `params.term` should be the term that is used for searching
    // `data.text` is the text that is displayed for the data object
    if (data.text.indexOf(params.term) > -1) {
      return data;
    }

    // checking if a value matches (my addition to their example)
    if (data.data.some(({Value}) => Value.includes(params.text)) {
      return data;
    }

    // Return `null` if the term should not be displayed
    return null;
}

$(".js-example-matcher").select2({
  matcher: matchCustom
});
```

You may have to modify my additions to match whatever your browser compatibility requirements are (i.e. I'm using fat-arrow functions, object destructuring, `String.prototype.includes`, and `Array.prototype.some`).

Comment: thanks. But I cannot get the children to show up in the select2 dropdown, nor does the search work. See my post above for a fiddle.

Comment: I'm afraid you're using Select2 version 3.x which as far as I can tell, doesn't support what you want. Version 4.x does however. Here's the modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b85swr3b/2/. (I'm not sure why you changed `data.data.some` to `data.data.Key` but that isn't a correct change).